# Undeserved association bonus

Tags: support

I was having some problems logging in - whenever I logged in through Google I got asked to confirm my new account, but I didn't want a new account, I wanted to access my old one. Eventually I asked for a password recovery e-mail and managed to log in and was asked if I wanted to add my Google ID to my account. I did and then I got an association bonus. What was going on?

Comment: Looks like maybe the first time the system realized you had another account with sufficient rep (MathOverflow)?

Comment: If you feel undeserved, you can always pay it forward with bounties. ;-)

Comment: Also. [This!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FucbvoFFy0)

Comment: @Isaac: that makes sense. It must have been my modest reputation on MathOverflow catching up with me. Thanks!

Comment: @Asaf Karagila: now I know it is not wholly undeserved, I will save it to spend on a rainy day.